# rails multiple level include on nested association

Tags: sql, ruby-on-rails, activerecord

I have 3 tables, comments, users, and images.

I'm trying to formulate a query that will product arrays of comments on a post that includes the commentator's information and a avatar.

The avatar is stored in the images table, while the users table contains the user info plus a reference id to the image object that stores the users avatar.

Each comment has a author id that is referencing an object in the user table.

This is what I have so far

```
@comments = Comment.all(:include => [:user => :images], 
            :conditions => {
              :source => p[:source], 
              :source_id => p[:id], 
              :users => {:id => p[:user_id]}, /* if this result is *user */
              :images => {????} /*essentially i need images.id = *user.profile_id */
              })
```

Can't get the image part to work, can someone show me how?

Comment: post the model code, if your model associations are right, you should be able to do @comments = User.find(:id).comments

Comment: `class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :images
  has_many :comments`

`class Image < ActiveRecord::Base
    belongs_to :user`

This is what you're looking for?

Comment: Shouldn't a user have only one avatar? Any reason why a user `has_many` images?

Comment: `OrderItem.all(:include => [{:product => :product_kit_skuss}])` This wasn't work with `rails 4.2`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is what I got working at the end

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
    belongs_to :image, :foreign_key => "profile_id"

class Image < ActiveRecord::Base
    has_one :user

class Comment < ActiveRecord::Base
    belongs_to :user

@comments = Comment.all(:include => [{:user => :image}, :like, :flag], 
            :conditions => {
              ...
              })
```

This works but if anyone can tell me if its the proper way to do this it would be great

Comment: why wouldn't we be using the `.includes` method?

Comment: In `rails 4.2` it is not working but on `3.2.13` it works.
What could be the syntex in rails 4