# How can I fetch associated tables with using includes()?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, activerecord

There are 4 tables such as **codes**, **users**, **user_profiles**, and **communities**.

The associations are set up just like this below.

**Code** belongs_to :user
**Code** belongs_to :community

**User** has_many :codes
**User** has_one :user_profile

**UserProfile** belongs_to :user

**Community** has_many :codes

If I want to use **includes()**

```
@communities = current_user.get_up_voted(Community)
@communities_ids = @communities.pluck(:id)

@codes = Code.includes(:user) \
             .where(:community_id => @communities_ids) \
             .order("users.active_at DESC") \
             .page(params[:page]) \
             .includes(:community, user: [:user_profile])
```

This won't work because of this part here.

```
includes(:community, user: [:user_profile])
```

But if I switch it to

```
includes(:community)
```

that works...

How can I add `user_profile` into includes?

Comment: May be you can get some idea from http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18473529/rails-multiple-level-include-on-nested-association

Comment: @RAJ... Thanks I took a look at the link. However it looks like the old way of coding style. Not for RoR 3 or higher

Comment: I edited your code a little for readability (and check out pluck, it's a nest method to use instead of collect)

Comment: Does it work if you just `includes(:community, :user)`?

Answer (score 1):

Your approach looks like it should basically be working... I would try using a Hash without the array for your `.includes` since there's only one association being added. And I would also suggest combining the 2 different `.includes` statements into one. So like this:

```
@codes = Code.includes(:community, user: :user_profile)
             .where(community_id: @communities_ids)
             .order("users.active_at DESC")
             .page(params[:page])
```

Comment: @pbobb Thanks for the answer. I tried that, too. But it takes forever to load a page somehow:( what is the problem...

Comment: Are your foreign keys indexed properly?